# Detecting text in a webpage with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a script to create tooltips that popup when a user hovers over a hot spot. Now, my specific uses will be for automatically attaching Bible references with a tooltip, much like RefTagger by Logos (http://reftagger.com/#download). I'm writing my own script - rather than using RefTagger - because 1) I love programming, I spend hours doing it, and 2) it's the easiest way to completely customize the look of the tooltips to match this website I'm creating.

Now, the thing that RefTagger does that I can't seem to figure out (After staring at their [source code](http://bible.logos.com/jsapi/referencetagging.js) for two days! I'm new-er to programming and occasionally have a hard time following a program that uses letters as variables for EVERYTHING) is that the JavaScript in RefTagger can automatically detect if a Bible reference is put to the text and format the tooltip around it . . . not to mention the mysteriously hidden Bibles it pulls the verses from in the first place.

I'm not sure if the program traverses the DOM to find the references or what, but the closest I could come to that was the "traverseDOM" method that was given to the object "b".
I'm not exactly sure I'm making sense here, but any help would be greatly appreciated, here's an example:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Rom 3:23</p>

<!-- RefTagger from Logos. Visit http://www.logos.com/reftagger. This code should appear directly before the </body> tag. -->
<script src="referenceTagging.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Logos.ReferenceTagging.lbsBibleVersion = "ESV";
    Logos.ReferenceTagging.lbsLinksOpenNewWindow = true;
    Logos.ReferenceTagging.lbsLogosLinkIcon = "dark";
    Logos.ReferenceTagging.lbsNoSearchTagNames = [ "h2", "h3", "h3" ];
    Logos.ReferenceTagging.lbsTargetSite = "biblia";
    Logos.ReferenceTagging.tag();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

That should come up as Rom 3:23 in link form, then hovering over it would normally bring up the tooltip but for me it's been saying it couldn't load the reference and I'm not sure why that's happening either. In any case, I'm most curious to know how the JavaScript in RefTagger detects Bible references in the HTML text. I really hope it isn't obvious :P

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to generate tooltips from titles or from classes 
http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html

or http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/

if you need to know why your example using reftagger do not work, read this

http://reftagger.com/#customize

**Why isn’t it working?**

1. Check to make sure that the JavaScript code is in the footer, preferably immediately before the closing `</body>` tag. RefTagger will only search for references in text that come before the JavaScript code.
2. Make sure your browser supports JavaScript, and that JavaScript is enabled in your browser settings.
3. Check to see if you have restricted RefTagger from searching the HTML tag that the Bible reference appears in. For example, if the reference appears in a bold `<b>` tag, ensure that you did not select Bold from the list of tags in the preferences.
4. RefTagger may not work when testing HTML pages on your local machine. If it has not been configured as a web server, you may see the message, “Sorry. This reference could not be loaded at this time,” when the mouse hovers over the reference hyperlink. Load the code to your web site and test it there instead.

Comment: thanks! and thank you for the links, I guess I must have looked past number four there :/

Comment: Yes, that was my first comment, so I changed it to an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're really after analyzing the source code you found I'll try to give my two cents.. first cent: they're using heavy weight regular expressions, here they are in all their glory:

```
b.lbsRefQuickTest = new RegExp("((\\d{1,3})(?:\\s?\\:\\s?|\\.)(\\d{1,3}(?:(?:\\s?(?:[a-z]|ff))(?=\\W|$))?))|(Ob(?:ad(?:iah)?)?|Ph(?:ilem(?:on)?|m)|(?:(?:2(?:nd\\s)?|[Ss]econd\\s|II\\s)|(?:3(?:rd\\s)?|[Tt]hird\\s|III\\s))\\s*J(?:o(?:hn?)?|h?n)|Jude?)", "i");
b.lbsRefRegExp = new RegExp("(\\W|^)((Z(?:e(?:p(?:h(?:aniah)?)?|c(?:h(?:ariah)?)?)|[pc])|W(?:is(?:d(?:om(?:\\s+of\\s+(?:Ben\\s+Sirah?|Solomon))?|.?\\s+of\\s+Sol))?|s)|T(?:ob(?:it)?|it(?:us)?|he(?:\\s+(?:Song\\s+of\\s+(?:Three\\s+(?:Youth|Jew)s|the\\s+Three\\s+Holy\\s+Children)|Re(?:velation|st\\s+of\\s+Esther))|ssalonians)|b)|S(?:us(?:anna)?|o(?:ng(?:\\s+(?:of\\s+(?:Thr(?:ee(?:\\s+(?:(?:Youth|Jew)s|Children))?)?|So(?:l(?:omon)?|ngs)|the\\s+Three\\s+Holy\\s+Children)|Thr))?)?|ir(?:a(?:c?h)?)?|OS)|R(?:u(?:th)?|o(?:m(?:ans)?)?|e(?:v(?:elation)?|st\\s+of\\s+Esther)?|[vm]|th)|Qoh(?:eleth)?|P(?:s(?:\\s+Sol(?:omon)?|a(?:lm(?:s(?:\\s+(?:of\\s+)?Solomon)?)?)?|Sol|s|l?m)?|r(?:ov(?:erbs)?|\\s+(?:(?:of\\s+)?Man|Az)|ayer\\s+of\\s+(?:Manasse[sh]|Azariah)|v)?|h(?:il(?:em(?:on)?|ippians)?|[pm])|Ma)|O(?:b(?:ad(?:iah)?)?|des)|N(?:u(?:m(?:bers)?)?|e(?:h(?:emiah)?)?|a(?:h(?:um)?)?|[mb])|M(?:rk?|ic(?:ah)?|a(?:t(?:t(?:hew)?)?|l(?:achi)?|r(?:k))|[tlk])|L(?:uke?|e(?:v(?:iticus)?|t(?:ter\\s+of\\s+Jeremiah|\\s+Jer))?|a(?:od(?:iceans)?|m(?:entations)?)?|[vk]|tr\\s+Jer|Je)|J(?:ud(?:g(?:es)?|ith|e)?|o(?:s(?:h(?:ua)?)?|n(?:ah)?|el?|hn|b)|nh?|e(?:r(?:emiah)?)?|d(?:th?|gs?)|a(?:me)?s|[ts]h|[rmlgb]|hn)|Is(?:a(?:iah)?)?|H(?:o(?:s(?:ea)?)?|e(?:b(?:rews)?)?|a(?:g(?:gai)?|b(?:akkuk)?)|g)|G(?:e(?:n(?:esis)?)?|a(?:l(?:atians)?)?|n)|E(?:z(?:ra?|e(?:k(?:iel)?)?|k)|x(?:o(?:d(?:us)?)?)?|s(?:th(?:er)?)?|p(?:ist(?:le\\s+(?:to\\s+(?:the\\s+)?Laodiceans|Laodiceans)|\\s+Laodiceans)|h(?:es(?:ians)?)?|\\s+Laod)?|c(?:cl(?:es(?:iast(?:icu|e)s)?|us)?)?|noch)|D(?:eut(?:eronomy)?|a(?:n(?:iel)?)?|[tn])|C(?:ol(?:ossians)?|anticle(?:\\s+of\\s+Canticle)?s)|B(?:el(?:\\s+and\\s+the\\s+Dragon)?|ar(?:uch)?)|A(?:m(?:os)?|dd(?:\\s+(?:Ps(?:alm)?|Es(?:th)?)|ition(?:s\\s+to\\s+Esther|al\\s+Psalm)|Esth)|c(?:(?:t)s)?|zariah|Es)|\u03C8|(?:4(?:th\\s)?|[Ff]ourth\\s|(?:IIII|IV)\\s)\\s*(?:Ma(?:c(?:c(?:abees)?)?)?)|(?:3(?:rd\\s)?|[Tt]hird\\s|III\\s)\\s*(?:Ma(?:c(?:c(?:abees)?)?)?|Jo(?:h(?:n)?)?|Jn\\.?|Jhn)|(?:(?:2(?:nd\\s)?|[Ss]econd\\s|II\\s)|(?:1(?:st\\s)?|[Ff]irst\\s|I\\s))\\s*(?:T(?:i(?:m(?:othy)?)?|h(?:es(?:s(?:alonians)?)?)?)|S(?:a(?:m(?:uel)?)?|m)?|P(?:e(?:t(?:er)?)?|t)|Ma(?:c(?:c(?:abees)?)?)?|K(?:i(?:n(?:gs)?)?|gs)|J(?:o(?:hn?)?|h?n)|Es(?:d(?:r(?:as)?)?)?|C(?:o(?:r(?:inthians)?)?|h(?:r(?:on(?:icles)?)?)?)))(?:\\.?\\s*(\\d{1,3})(?:\\s?\\:\\s?|\\.)(\\d{1,3}(?:(?:\\s?(?:[a-z]|ff))(?=\\W|$))?)(\\s?(?:-|--|\\u2013|\\u2014)\\s?\\d{1,3}(?:(?:\\s?(?:[a-z]|ff))(?=\\W|$))?((?:\\s?\\:\\s?|\\.)\\d{1,3}(?:(?:\\s?(?:[a-z]|ff))(?=\\W|$))?)?(?!\\s*(?:T(?:i(?:m(?:othy)?)?|h(?:es(?:s(?:alonians)?)?)?)|S(?:a(?:m(?:uel)?)?|m)?|P(?:e(?:t(?:er)?)?|t)|Ma(?:c(?:c(?:abees)?)?)?|K(?:i(?:n(?:gs)?)?|gs)|J(?:o(?:hn?)?|h?n)|Es(?:d(?:r(?:as)?)?)?|C(?:o(?:r(?:inthians)?)?|h(?:r(?:on(?:icles)?)?)?))(?:\\W)))?)|(Ob(?:ad(?:iah)?)?|Ph(?:ilem(?:on)?|m)|(?:(?:2(?:nd\\s)?|[Ss]econd\\s|II\\s)|(?:3(?:rd\\s)?|[Tt]hird\\s|III\\s))\\s*J(?:o(?:hn?)?|h?n)|Jude?)\\s*\\d{1,3}(?:(?:\\s?(?:[a-z]|ff))(?=\\W|$))?(?:\\s?(?:-|--|\\u2013|\\u2014)\\s?\\d{1,3}(?:(?:\\s?(?:[a-z]|ff))(?=\\W|$))?)?)([,]?\\s?(?:"+h.join("|")+")|[,]?\\s?[(](?:"+h.join("|")+")[)])?",(b.lbsCaseInsensitive?"i":""));
b.lbsBookContRegExp = new RegExp("^((?:(?:[,;\\.]+)?\\s?(?:and|or|&|&amp;)?)\\s*(?:(?:(?:cf|Cf|CF)[.,]?\\s?(?:v(?:v|ss?)?[.]?)?)[.,]?\\s*)?)((\\d{1,3})(?:\\s?\\:\\s?|\\.)\\d{1,3}(?:(?:\\s?(?:[a-z]|ff))(?=\\W|$))?(?:\\s?(?:-|--|\\u2013|\\u2014)\\s?\\d{1,3}(?:(?:\\s?\\:\\s?|\\.)\\d{1,3}(?:(?:\\s?(?:[a-z]|ff))(?=\\W|$))?)?)?)");
b.lbsChapContRegExp = new RegExp("^((?:(?:[,;\\.]+)?\\s?(?:and|or|&|&amp;)?)\\s*(?:(?:(?:cf|Cf|CF)[.,]?\\s?(?:v(?:v|ss?)?[.]?)?)[.,]?\\s*)?)(\\d{1,3}(?:(?:\\s?(?:[a-z]|ff))(?=\\W|$))?(?:\\s?(?:-|--|\\u2013|\\u2014)\\s?\\d{1,3}(?:(?:\\s?(?:[a-z]|ff))(?=\\W|$))?)?)(?!\\s*(?:st|nd|rd|th|T(?:i(?:m(?:othy)?)?|h(?:es(?:s(?:alonians)?)?)?)|S(?:a(?:m(?:uel)?)?|m)?|P(?:e(?:t(?:er)?)?|t)|Ma(?:c(?:c(?:abees)?)?)?|K(?:i(?:n(?:gs)?)?|gs)|J(?:o(?:hn?)?|h?n)|Es(?:d(?:r(?:as)?)?)?|C(?:o(?:r(?:inthians)?)?|h(?:r(?:on(?:icles)?)?)?)))"
```

Second cent: the so called `traverseDom` is their own custom function (no JS magic) that does as its name suggest: recursively traverse all DOM elements, looking for match on one of the above regular expressions. Here is the function in readable format:

```
function traverseDom(f,y,t) {
    var n = t || 0;
    if(n > b.lbsMaxTreeDepth) {
        return 0
    }

    var m = 0, l = false, g = (f.tagName || "").toLowerCase(), q = f.className ? f.className.split(" ") : [], p = false, v, o, u, x;
    for (v = 0, o = b.lbsNoSearchClassNames.length; v<o; v++) {
        for(u = 0, x = q.length; u <x ;u++) {
            if (b.lbsNoSearchClassNames[v].toLowerCase() == q[u].toLowerCase()) {
                p = true;
                break
            }
        }
        if(p) {
            break
        }
    }

    if (f.nodeType === 3) {
        var r = f.nodeValue;
        m = b.refSearch(r, f, null, null, null, y)
    }
    else {
        if (g.length > 0 && (!b.lbsNoSearchTags[g] || g === "a") && !p) {
            y=null;
            if (g === "a") {
                var s = /^libronixdls:/i;
                if (s.test(f.href)) {
                    if((b.lbsAppendIconToLibLinks || b.lbsAppendIconToLogosLinks) && !(f.lastChild && f.lastChild.tagName && f.lastChild.tagName.toLowerCase() === "img")) {
                        b.insertLibLink(f, null)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if(/bibleref/.test(f.className.toLowerCase())) {
                        l = b.tagBibleref(f, function(A, i, j) {
                            var C = b.normalizeReference(i), B = j || b.lbsBibleVersion;
                            b.addLinkAttributes(A, C, B)
                        })
                    }
                    else {
                        if (b.lbsConvertHyperlinks === true && f.childNodes.length === 1 && f.firstChild.nodeType === 3) {
                            var w = b.lbsHyperlinkTestList.length === 0;
                            for (var h in b.lbsHyperlinkTestList) {
                                if (f.href.toLowerCase().indexOf(h.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
                                    w=true;
                                    break
                                }
                            }
                            if (w) {
                                y = f
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (y === null) {
                    return m
                }
            }

            if(g === "cite" && (/bibleref/).test(f.className.toLowerCase())) {
                l = b.tagBibleref(f,function(A,i,j) {
                    b.insertRefNode(i, A.innerHTML, j, A.firstChild);
                    A.removeChild(A.lastChild)
                })
            }

            if(!l) {
                var k = f.childNodes;
                v=0;
                while(v < k.length) {
                    var z = b.traverseDom(k[v], y, n+1);
                    v += z+1
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return m
}
```

Comment: Ok, here's a silly question that, for the life of me . . . I cannot find an answer to on the internet. :( what does "var n = t || 0;" mean?! Am I correct in assuming that the double pipe symbol is referring to the Boolean operator "OR", would that mean "n" would either be true or false?

To be honest, I'm a freshman in college majoring in Computer Science, and I just finished my first programming class which was really just about basic programming ideas. But through the course I basically fell in love with JavaScript, but I haven't learned it all yet!

Comment: Yes it is OR and the result is that if t has any of the falsy values "", false, 0, undefined or null, assign 0 to n otherwise assign t to n

Comment: hm, then couldn't it also be written: "var n = t ? t : 0;"?

Comment: Yes. It could be written like that too. I missed the number NaN in my list of falsy values: http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript

Comment: @Zach the `||` operator is used to elegantly put default value if something is null/empty - same result as using `? ... :` but more elegant to most programmers. Personal comment if I may: you chose yourself impossible mission here, starting to learn with such complex code - it's like learning to swim in the deepest ocean without any life belt.

Comment: Thank you both for your timely answers!

@Shadow Wizard, I appreciate your concern and to a degree I agree with you. This stuff has been pretty difficult for me! But that's what I find so much fun about it. I guess I figure that I learn a lot just by piecing together how complex code works, and also it pushes me to do more research to learn more and more about programming. I guess it's kind of a win/lose deal.

Comment: @Zach OK, that's your call.. feel free to ask more, I'm sure the `||` isn't the only wall you're trying to climb. :)

Comment: Haha, yeah . . . I dunno if you'll see this but at the very end of this program there is the tag method that calls the traverseDom method: b.traverseDom(f || b.lbsRootNode || a); Now I understand that the traverseDom method takes three arguments or parameters, but I really don't understand this function call . . .

Comment: @Zach yep saw that - unlike "compiled" languages, in JavaScript you're not forced to pass all parameters to a function - in such case, the parameters you don't pass will have special value of `undefined`. So that function call is passing one of three as the first parameter: `f`, `b.lbsRootNode` or `a` (the first that has value) and leave the other two undefined, as you see in the recursive call they're being passed. By the way when posting comment use @usernamehere to notify the person, I see this only because I'm following this question but most people won't do that.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure if the program traverses
>   the DOM to find the references or what

What *else* would it do?  When your program loads, you have to find all the text elements, find the references in them (using a suitable regexp) and replace them with an appropriate `cite` element.

Having the marked-up cite elements actually produce the tool-tip is the next challenge.